# Custom diff by textconv in SourceTree

Tags: mysql, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to compare and merge MySQL WorkBench files in SourceTree, and in order to do so I created a small shell script that extracts the content of the .mwb file and strips some useless counters from the XML file inside it.
Then I added this line to .gitconfig in the project's root:

```
[diff "mwbdiff"]
    textconv = mwb-diff
```

and this in the .gitattributes:

```
*.mwb diff=mwbdiff
```

Now, if I change something on a .mwb, then "git diff" on console shows the correct differences, and SourceTree does it, too:

[image: uncommitted changes]

The problem is that if I try to do the same on already committed versions, I get nothing:

[image]

Same result if I try to merge. I still get the right output if I try to run GIT from the console like this:

```
git diff develop feature/four -- test.mwb
```

but if I try to merge, then I get unsolved conflicts and I don't know how to proceed.

I also tried to move the .gitattributes and .gitconfig changes into the global variables, and it actually works in the console, but it didn't help SourceTree.

I suspect it has something to do with the binary preview in SourceTree (Mac version), if I could disable it...

What am I missing? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not supported.

> So to avoid calling `git diff` when it will ultimately just produce no output, SourceTree pre-detects whether files are binary or text on the disk, identified by whether in a quick sample of the initial chunk of the file contains a couple of binary zero's in succession. I can only assume that the odt formats include this sequence, so SourceTree treats them as binary. On Mac we have a binary preview pane which displays before/after of supported binary files but we haven't ported that to Windows yet.
>
> At the moment we don't support your case and may not add it in the near future, because it's a pretty rare thing to do and most people would just see a performance penalty when `git diff` fails and we then fall back on other techniques. We'll keep this logged for possible future support.

Source: *[JIRA - textconv diff not generated](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1416)*

So in other words, SourceTree specifically *avoids* calling `git diff` for files that SourceTree considers to be binary. That means that any textconvs don't get called at all.

The only way to work around this would be to trick SourceTree into thinking that your file isn't binary. Which is probably not feasible.