# How to git diff Word docx files in Sourcetree on Windows

Tags: git, docx, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff

I would like to see git diff of Word .docx files in SourceTree on Windows.

Per default they shows up like this:
[image: Word .docx files in SourceTree history]

I have tried [changing .gitattributes and .git\config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734617/diff-word-docx-files-in-sourcetree-on-windows-7) but it does not work for the history in SourceTree. This sadly seems like a limitation in SourceTree [1](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1416), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680291/custom-diff-by-textconv-in-sourcetree)

Are there any ways to get a diff for Word .docx files in SourceTree on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

## End result

This solution will merge for comparison using the [Word - Compare and merge two versions of a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-and-merge-two-versions-of-a-document-f5059749-a797-4db7-a8fb-b3b27eb8b87e). Using it like this:

1. Select a commit in SourceTree
2. Select a .docx in the file list
3. Click the gear icon to the far right
4. Select **External Diff**

You can also use **Ctrl + D** as a shortcut for **External Diff**

**Drawbacks**

- Does not work in SourceTree's own History view
- Overwrites the **External Diff Tool** in case you are using another

## Setup

This solution is based on [ForNeVeR/ExtDiff](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/ExtDiff).

First you create 2 files:

**CompareWord.cmd**

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -File "%~dpn0.ps1" %*
```

**CompareWord.ps1**

```
param(
    [string] $BaseFileName,
    [string] $ChangedFileName
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

function resolve($relativePath) {
    (Resolve-Path $relativePath).Path
}

$BaseFileName = resolve $BaseFileName
$ChangedFileName = resolve $ChangedFileName

# Remove the readonly attribute because Word is unable to compare readonly
# files:
$baseFile = Get-ChildItem $BaseFileName
if ($baseFile.IsReadOnly) {
    $baseFile.IsReadOnly = $false
}

# Constants
$wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
$wdCompareTargetNew = 2

try {
    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $word.Visible = $true
    $document = $word.Documents.Open($BaseFileName, $false, $false)
    $document.Compare($ChangedFileName, [ref]"Comparison", [ref]$wdCompareTargetNew, [ref]$true, [ref]$true)

    $word.ActiveDocument.Saved = 1

    # Now close the document so only compare results window persists:
    $document.Close([ref]$wdDoNotSaveChanges)
} catch {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($_.Exception)
}
```

1. Launch SourceTree
2. Open **Tools** → **Options**
3. Go to the **Diff** tab
4. Under **External Diff / Merge** → **External Diff Tool:** choose **Custom**
5. Under **Diff Command:** write the full path to the CompareWord.cmd, i.e. `<your\path\to\>CompareWord.cmd`
6. Under **Arguments:** write `\"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"`
7. Click **OK** to save your settings